# vue.js with vue-multilanguage My webpack compilate is not translated right

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, vue.js, babeljs

My webpack compilate is not transpiled into the right JS. It writes

`exports default MultiLanguage`
instead of
`module.exports = { MultiLanguage: MultiLanguage};`

My .bablerc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My app",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-multilanguage": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "author": "You"
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {

        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**And therefor the error and the code where it hits** in the build.js
in Chromium/Chrome und ubuntu:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`

in Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
    export default MultiLanguage
```

Here also the vue code (main.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import MultiLanguage from 'vue-multilanguage/src/vue-multilanguage.js'

Vue.use(MultiLanguage, {
    default: 'en',
    en: {
        hi: 'Hello',
        welcome: 'Welcome, {name}'
    },
    pt: {
        hi: 'Ola',
        welcome: 'Bem-vindo, {name}'
    }
})
```

any recommanded tutorials? any idea?

when I replace the line in build.js wit `module.exports = { MultiLanguage: MultiLanguage};` the error does not occure

Comment: I've never used the element property syntax that you are using before. That could be causing your error. Have you checked the console? I can just about bet that vue is having problem rendering your template because of the v.lang.welcome property. I don't think that is proper html5.

Comment: I must confess. I copid it from the Tutorial of the module

Comment: I would recommend looking for another tutorial because the syntax you are using looks unlike anything I have ever seen.

Comment: @MiguelCabrera the syntax looks good according to: https://github.com/leonardovilarinho/vue-multilanguage (the tutorial of the makers of the module)

Comment: You could be right, but I've been writing code exclusively in Vue2 for over a year and I've never seen the `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'`, usually I just `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: OK, but it has nothing to do with the Point, that I don't get the right ecs5 Out , right?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is linked to your import.

`vue-multilanguage.js` is not provided pre-compiled by its author (which is rare, usually libraries include a dist file ready to be used...) and as it is in your `node_modules` folder, it is not transformed from ES6 to ES5 by your babel loader as well. You need to add an exception in your `webpack.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {

        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        // exclude everything from node_modules, except vue-multilanguage
        exclude: /node_modules(?![\\/]vue-multilanguage[\\/])/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Not directly related, but not that I also replaced `'babel'` by `'babel-loader'`, to avoid some bugs with older packages. [See here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#the-node-api-for-babel-has-been-moved-to-babel-core).

Also, you can (and you probably should), as mentioned in the comments, import vue this way.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
```

**Side note**:

According to their `package.json`, there **should** be a file ready to be used in their library, located at `dist/vue-multilanguage.js`. But they oddly added their dist folder into their `.npmignore` file, and so it's not included. That's probably an error. I'll post an issue on their github. Once it's corrected, and if you update your package, you should be able to simply import vue-multi like this (without adding any exception to your webpack config):

```js
import MultiLanguage from 'vue-multilanguage'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I cannot import vue without the path. Why?
And I changed the exlude part and still have the plain ES6 export in my build.js. any idea, do you need any information?

Comment: And when I replace the line again I get an other error: build.js:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: lang

Comment: I hosted on github a minimal working version, see if there is any difference with yours: https://github.com/cobaltway/vue-multi-integration

Comment: I had no Time to check your solution so far. As the bounty would have run out tomorow, I award your great help anyway today.

Answer (score 0):

I would use next imports:

```
import Vue from './vue';
import MultiLanguage from './vue-multilanguage';
```